# During reentry, does the flux stay laminar? Should become turbulent the capsule could not mantain attitude

Tags: reentry, atmosphere

This a thing that, instinctively, I find it hard to grasp. The capsules are designed with a centre of gravity slightly to the direction of the thermal shield, this assures the right attitude, but how can it remain stable, at such velocities and plasma flow, I find it hard to believe, but it is so!

Comment: What sort of instabilities do you foresee?

Comment: Turbulent flow is chaotic by definition

Answer (score 4):

Reentry vehicles have a turbulent wake, and a transition region exists at some point along the body.

[image]

[image]

The paper [Laminar-Turbulent Transition on Reentry
Capsules and Planetary Probes](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Eaae519/BAM6QT-Mach-6-tunnel/reviewpapers/capsule-plprobe-blt-jsr-dec2006.pdf) has a good overview.

Shuttle images from [The HYTHIRM Project: Flight Thermography of the Space
Shuttle During Hypersonic Re-entry](http://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20100000137/downloads/20100000137.pdf%3Fattachment%3Dtrue&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V0ktYJv-Ns-NywS944_ACw&scisig=AAGBfm20Lnmpgjt8i17tuo1LkjyWyD81Vg&nossl=1&oi=scholarr)